# Simulink stuck at "compiling: evaluating block parameters"

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to run a model in Simulink, available for download [here](http://csel.asu.edu/?q=node/33) ([direct](http://csel.asu.edu/downloads/Software/TEmatlab.zip)).

I have been able to run it on a Linux machine, but on Windows it seems to get stuck at the compiling step. At the bottom of the screen I see two green bars, and the message "compiling: evaluating block parameters." It never goes beyond this.

I have tried choosing a compiler using the `mex -setup` process, but to be honest, I suspect this is not even close to what I need to do.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the windows and linux machine comparable? Matlab version, Simulink version, 32/64 bit? Furthermore, the easiest solution may be to just compile it on another machine and hope that it works.

Comment: Dear Dennis,  Thanks, it is a 64-bit machine. After reading your answer I checked and I believe this could be the issue. I'll give the recommended solution a shot. Regards.